# Is it possible to do xcm transfers between parachains without a channel opened?

Tags: parachain, xcm, parachain-launch

I'm experiencing something that I consider some weird behavior :)

I set up two parachains and somehow I can transfer native tokens between them without opening a channel :O

Here you can find the details of the xcm transfer, https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-e2e/blob/4aac538e4dc8ee579aa92d5964931962137e6a10/testPad/xTokens.testpad.test.ts#L76

I'm running both "same" chains with parachain-launch on `rococo-local` chain,

```
relaychain:
  image: parity/polkadot:v0.9.42
  chain: rococo-local
  runtimeGenesisConfig:
    configuration:
      config:
        validation_upgrade_cooldown: 10
        validation_upgrade_delay: 10
  env:
    RUST_LOG: parachain::candidate-backing=trace,parachain::candidate-selection=trace,parachain::pvf=trace,parachain::collator-protocol=trace,parachain::provisioner=trace
  flags:
    - --rpc-methods=unsafe
    - --wasm-execution=compiled
    - --execution=wasm
  nodes:
    - name: alice
    - name: bob

parachains:
- image: mangatasolutions/mangata-node:develop
  chain:
    base: rococo-local
    collators:
      - alice
      - bob
    sudo: alice
    skipCollatorSelection: true
    skipBalances: true
  id: 2110
  parachain: true
  flags:
    - --rpc-methods=unsafe
    - --force-authoring
    - --wasm-execution=compiled
    - --execution=wasm
  relaychainFlags:
    - --wasm-execution=compiled
    - --execution=wasm
  env:
    # RUST_LOG: info,block_builder=trace,block_shuffler=trace,runtime::ver=trace,txpool=trace,rpc::nonce=trace
    RUST_LOG: info,block_builder=trace
  volumePath: /mangata/data
  nodes:
  - flags:
    - --alice
  - flags:
    - --bob
- image: mangatasolutions/mangata-node:develop
  chain:
    base: rococo-local
    collators:
      - alice
      - bob
    sudo: alice
    skipCollatorSelection: true
    skipBalances: true
  id: 2001
  parachain: true
  flags:
    - --rpc-methods=unsafe
    - --force-authoring
    - --wasm-execution=compiled
    - --execution=wasm
  relaychainFlags:
    - --wasm-execution=compiled
    - --execution=wasm
  env:
    # RUST_LOG: info,block_builder=trace,block_shuffler=trace,runtime::ver=trace,txpool=trace,rpc::nonce=trace
    RUST_LOG: info,block_builder=trace
  volumePath: /mangata/data
  nodes:
  - flags:
    - --alice
  - flags:
    - --bob
```

[image: Pic about relay handling]

Answer (score 1):

Impossible. Actually what you attach is some `ump` message in relaychain not the `hrmp` between parachain.